# In OpenVPN 2.4, how do I support multiple ciphers?

Tags: openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server(installed via apt-get) on a Vultr VPS, and I would like it to support both aes and blowfish(yes, I know about SWEET32). When I use

```
--ncp-disable
```

it only uses the first cipher. I would like the server to support both ciphers, and for the client config to specify which cipher to use.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking in to this, apparently if you list ciphers like (config file style):

```
cipher BF-CBC
cipher AES-256-GCM
```

Or (command line):

```
--cipher BF-CBC --cipher AES-256-GCM
```

Only the last one will be used.

You can only allow a list of ciphers in the NCP settings, like (config file):

```
ncp-ciphers AES-256-GCM:BF-CBC
```

Or (command line):

```
--ncp-ciphers AES-256-GCM:BF-CBC
```

According to the [docs](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage) you can't have multiple ciphers and have NCP disabled